# Use casting instead of CFStringRef getting contact information

Tags: iphone, objective-c, casting

I've got a doubt about using "CFStringRef". I've seen several examples of managing iPhone contacts and in most of them they use:

```
...
ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
CFStringRef emailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, 0);
...
NSString *email = (NSString *)emailRef;
```

I don't know why CFStringRef is used instead of using casting:

```
...
ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
NSString *email = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, 0);
...
```

Is it conventional to use CFStringRef? Is it correct to use direct casting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [CFString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html) is “toll-free bridged” with its Cocoa Foundation counterpart,
>   NSString. This means that the Core Foundation type is interchangeable
>   in function or method calls with the bridged Foundation object.
>   Therefore, in a method where you see an NSString * parameter, you can
>   pass in a CFStringRef, and in a function where you see a CFStringRef
>   parameter, you can pass in an NSString instance. This also applies to
>   concrete subclasses of NSString.

Both are same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, the first example just uses an extra temporary variable. Performing a straight cast is perfectly OK, although you should pay attention to the memory management aspect. It sounds like `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex` returns a retained object although the documentation isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About releasing memory, as far as I know it's neccessary to release it (using `CFRelease(emailRef)`) as I've seen in this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html)